# Can I restore from Time Machine even when encryption is not finished?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption

My external drive is not encrypted and therefore the Time Machine takes FOR EVER to encrypt the disk after backing my computer up.

I estimate about 1 to 2 weeks minimum with the computer on every night.

In this situation, could I restore my computer from a backup even when Time Machine didn't finish encrypting the data?

Comment: Are you saying your external WASN'T encrypted, but you've now turned on encryption?  Is this drive an SSD or HDD? APFS or HFS?

Comment: HDD. 
It was not formatted with the encryption option. But timemachine now encrypts the copy. Yeap.

Comment: Are you speaking of there Enthalten of the external disk ö did you configure Time Machine to encrypt the backup? Please edit your question to add a step by step description of what you did.

Comment: Did you turn on encryption for TM? Do you want it encrypted?

Comment: I'm not sure why there's so much confusion about the encryption. 1. My external HDD wasn't formatted with encryption (Mac OS Extended without encryption) but TM  allows you to encrypt the backup.  Related: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7813232